# two different virtual hosts, one page displayed

Tags: virtualhost

I have two different sites configured using virtual hosts (the content of the virtualhost files is posted below) i just copied the default file and edited a few lines...

When i direct my browser to either of the two sites, only the content of the first of the two appears...

Why?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin majd.al@gmail.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/hunterprojects.com/public_html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/hunterprojects.com/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

AND THE SECOND ONE:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin majd.al@gmail.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/dodolabarchive.ca/public_html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/dodolabarchive.ca/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be missing the ServerName section of your Virtual hosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin majd.al@gmail.com
    ServerName hunterprojects.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hunterprojects.com/public_html
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin majd.al@gmail.com
    ServerName dodolabarchive.ca
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dodolabarchive.ca/public_html
```

Here is a link to apache documentation as well which has some more information on this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#servername